# CSS - Make divs align horizontally

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a container div with a fixed `width` and `height`, with `overflow: hidden`.

I want a horizontal row of float: left divs within this container. Divs which are floated left will naturally push onto the 'line' below after they read the right bound of their parent. This will happen even if the `height` of the parent should not allow this. This is how this looks:

[image: Wrong]

How I would like it to look:

![Right][2] - *removed image shack image that had been replaced by an advert*

Note: the effect I want can be achieved by using inline elements & `white-space: no-wrap` (that is how I did it in the image shown). This, however, is no good to me (for reasons too lengthy to explain here), as the child divs need to be floated block level elements.

Comment: Your image links seem to have broken. If you still have the originals, please reupload them to stack.imgur. Thanks!

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You may put an inner div in the container that is enough wide to hold all the floated divs.

```css
#container {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
}

#inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 2000px;
}

.child {
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I then make the outter div center? I tried add align="center" on the outter div, seems doesn't work.

Comment: This works for percentage widths too. In my case I'm using a container div with `width: 200%;` and the child elements are each `width: 50%;`. I can then use `transform: translateX(n%);` on the container to emulate a carousel effect as long as I have a parent container with `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 34):

`style="overflow:hidden"` for parent `div` and `style="float: left"` for all the child `divs` are important to make the `divs` align horizontally for old browsers like IE7 and below.

For modern browsers, you can use `style="display: table-cell"` for all the child `divs` and it would render horizontally properly.

Answer (score 14):

You can now use css flexbox to  align divs horizontally and vertically if you need to. general formula goes like this

```css
parent-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* for horizontal aligning of child divs */
  justify-content: center;
  /* for vertical aligning */
  align-items: center;
}

child-div {
  width: /* yoursize for each div */
  ;
}
```

Comment: elegant solution.

Answer (score 6):

This seems close to what you want:

```css
#foo {
  background: red;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.bar {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use the `clip` property:

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px,200px,100px,0px);
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}
```

note the `position: absolute` and `overflow: hidden` needed in order to get `clip` to work.

Comment: what is clip's browser support?

Comment: From http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp: 

The clip property is supported in all major browsers.

Note: The value "inherit" is not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports "inherit".

Answer (score 3):

Float: left, display: inline-block will both fail to align the elements horizontally if they exceed the width of the container.

It's important to note that the container should not wrap if the elements MUST display horizontally:
    `white-space: nowrap`

Answer (score -1):

Float them left.  In Chrome, at least, you don't need to have a wrapper, `id="container"`, in LucaM's example.