# Horizontal Align of two divs

Tags: html, css, alignment

I know that there are many threads about that subject, 
but I cannot understand why my code is not working. 
I have found a good sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931154/how-to-position-three-divs-in-html-horizontally) 
So i have a div and I want to display two other divs in it - next to each other. 
The green one has to be displayed on the left side and fill 75% horizontally and the blue one only 25% but displayed horizontally next to the green div and not vertically.

See the code:

```
 <div class="section2">
            <div class="referencesPics"> 
                <div class="line1">
                    <div class="leftPic">
                    hi
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightPic">
                    hallo
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="line2">
                    <div class="leftPic">
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightPic">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="line3">
                    <div class="leftPic">
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightPic">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="line4">
                    <div class="leftPic">
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightPic">
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>        
        </div>
```

the CSS:

```
.section2 {
    height:100%;
}

.section2 .referencesPics {
    height:25%;
}

.section2 .referencesPics .line1 {
    height:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1; vertical-align: top;
}

.section2 .referencesPics .line1 .leftPic {
    height:100%;
    width:75%;
    background-color:green;
    display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1; vertical-align: top;
}

.section2 .referencesPics .line1 .rightPic {
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    background-color:yellow;
display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1; vertical-align: top;
}

.section2 .referencesPics .line2 {
    height:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
}

.section2 .referencesPics .line3 {
    height:100%;
    background-color:brown;
}

.section2 .referencesPics .line4 {
    height:100%;
    background-color:green;
}
```

and also see the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xf0w1925/)

Thanks for help!

Comment: You have a lot of weird css code. You change the height of section2 7 times. But for your problem. Use float: left; or float:right; instead of: display: inline-block; display:inline; zoom:1 vertical-align: top;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated your code have a look at this.

```css
.section2 {
  width: 100%;
}
.leftPic {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: green;
  float: left
}
.rightPic {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="section2">
  <div class="referencesPics">
    <div class="line1">
      <div class="leftPic">
        hi
      </div>
      <div class="rightPic">
        hallo
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="line1">
      <div class="leftPic">
        hi
      </div>
      <div class="rightPic">
        hallo
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work with `display:inline-block` but you are gonna have to remove the whitespace in the html between the divs for this to work correctly

```
.line1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.leftPic {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: green;
  display:inline-block;
}
.rightPic {
  width: 25%;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

You can also of course do it with floats which will require extra steps in clearing them.

Here is the working [solution](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/qdMoGP?editors=110)