# CSS 100% divs side by side, Horizontal flow

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to do some step by step (4 steps in total) checkout. I thought about having a kind of a horizontal slider setup.

I created a container with a width of 400% containing 4 containers. These containers should be side by side and fill 100% of the Window. This is kind of a horizontal slider but i want to use it as a form.

[[[Container 1][Container 2][Container 3][Container 4]]]

My html:

```
    <div class="container fullWidth">

        <div id="checkoutContainer">

            <div class="checkout" id="cart">Cart</div>
            <div class="checkout" id="contact">Contact</div>
            <div class="checkout" id="address">Addresse</div>
            <div class="checkout" id="overview">Übersicht</div>
            <div class="checkout" id="thankyou">Danke</div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.container.fullWidth {
    width : 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

div#checkoutContainer {
    background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
    background-repeat : repeat-x;
    width : 500%;
    height : 657px;
}

div#checkoutContainer div.checkout {
    float : left;
    width : 900px;
    height : 657px;
}
```

The question is now: Can i somehow make the single divs fill the width of the page without using javascript (I know i can detect the page width and set the width)? Setting `div.checkout { width : 100% }`does not work as they will stack on each other then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - Make divs align horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103/css-make-divs-align-horizontally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/DTTnB/

You can fine-tune this how you want

I took off `overflow-x: hidden` so you can see that they lie horizontally 
.
you were on the right track

Key differences:

I made each of the containers only a proportion of their wrapping container:

.checkout: 
`width : 20%;`

Their wrapping container I made it wide enough to accommodate all containers so that each container would take up at least the page width.

checkoutContainer:

`width : 1000%;`
you can fine tune this

Answer (score 6):

Check out [my approach](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jjuiz), divs will fill the container so no need to 'fine tune', plus it is responsive and not dependent on the number of divs

**HTML**

```
<div id="checkoutContainer">
    <div class="checkout" id="cart">Cart</div>
    <div class="checkout" id="contact">Contact</div>
    <div class="checkout" id="address">Addresse</div>
    <div class="checkout" id="overview">Übersicht</div>
    <div class="checkout" id="thankyou">Danke</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#checkoutContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
.checkout {
    display:inline-block;
    width : 100%;
    height : 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[See working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jjuiz)

Comment: Very fancy and clean. Congrats. :3