# Divs side-by-side, centred, and overflowing edge of screen

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to design a landing page to link to 2 web apps. I am trying to make the design as visually attractive as possible. I think it would look good if the Divs containing the links were side-by-side at the centre of the screen, with their edges overflowing the left and right of the screen. I can then put a `border-radius` on them and some nice blocky colour:

**Goal:**

[image]

I have tried numerous options, including `inline-block` and `overflow:hidden`:

**HTML**

```
<div id="centre-pane">
    <div class="app-btn">
        <a href="l1.php"><img src="icon.png">link text</a>
    </div>
    <div class="app-btn">
        <a href="l2.php"><img src="icon2.png">link text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.app-btn 
{
    width:1000px;
    height:320px;

    display:inline-block;
    border:10px solid black;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

#centre-pane {   
    width:2000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Is this possible? I have found several ways of getting them side-by-side (eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506822/css-100-divs-side-by-side-horizontal-flow)) but nothing that also lets them overflow the screen.

Comment: Why do they need to overflow if you're hiding the overflow? Not sure what you are trying to do here

Comment: I suppose they don't, but I would like the _appearance_ of half of a `border-radius` box if that makes sense.

Comment: Since you know the dimensions you could do it like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/bsu9onsc/1/

try to change the width of the frame and you will see how the buttons follow (set som overflow hidden to hide scroll (as in version /2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using position absolute would do the trick.

I've added a wrapper but it may not be required.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html,
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.btn {
  width: 45%;
  height: 30%;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.left {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 25% 25% 0;
  border-left: none;
}
.right {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 25% 0 0 25%;
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="btn left"></div>
  <div class="btn right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks! Your original comment made me remember that you can set the `border-radius` independently for each corner, which of course means it actually doesn't have to overflow. 

Worth noting though, in Firefox at least that the `border-radius: % % % %` syntax draws funny elliptical radiuses, so I am going to instead use `border-top-left-radius` etc. which seems to work fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with absolute positioning and negative margins (for the right item). You'll have to fix the size of the `body` though in order to achieve the effect. I've also added individual classes to the first and second item respectively (`.app-btn-1` and `.app-btn-2`):

```
body {
    width: 2000px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.app-btn {
    width:1000px;
    height:320px;
    position: absolute;
    border:10px solid black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.app-btn-1 {
    left: -500px;
    text-align: right;
}

.app-btn-2 {
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -500px;
```

}

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pfkhubzm/2/)

**NOTE: For my demo to look right in jsfiddle, I've quartered the sizes so you can see the effect in the small window**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need:

```css
.menu {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: calc(50% - 100px);    
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: brown;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.menu:hover {
    background-color: gray;
    border-color: brown;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><div class="menu" id="left">Left</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="menu" id="right">Right</div></a>
```

I made a 
[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/gcu9dnz5/) for you.