# ASP.NET Repeater Horizontal

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, repeater

When I bind a list to my Repeater, it shows all the items in the list vertically.

Is it possible to show it horizontal?

Thanks

EDIT: I think I need to use HTML which I read from the comments.

Comment: Please provide more information. Repeaters just render whatever HTML you give it - it doesn't design anything for you. So if it's not doing what you want, then your HTML is the problem and can be looked at.

Comment: @JoeEnos is quite right - depending onr your html you should be able to acheive what you want by changing your markup and/or adding some CSS classes

Comment: Ooh so I need to put some html in the repeater what makes it horizontal?

Comment: Search for "CSS horizonatal div" (or wahtever tag your repeater's code generates for each row). I.e. possible duplicate of [CSS - Make divs align horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103/css-make-divs-align-horizontally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to the ASP.NET Repeater control is to use an ASP.NET DataList control, like this:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlContacts" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatColumns="2" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2">
    <ItemTemplate>
        // Put your markup structure here
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Read [ASP.NET DataList Rolodex](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Rolodex-with-Alphabetic-Filtering-using-ASP.Net-DataList.aspx) for an example of how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

YEs you can.

on each element , wrap it / or apply to it a `float` style (`float:left`) or make it `inline` style and it will align left automatically :

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, the Repeater control does not allow you to set the `RepeatDirection`. You can either use a [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection.aspx), which does have such property (`RepeatDirection`) or use CSS to make sure that elements render horizontally first until they fill the available width and then continue to the next row.