# Setting margin-left from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So here's my issue. This is what I want to do

[image]

Which I did. The issue is the blue text doesn't align up correctly. Since I'm doing `margin-left: 130` on the blue text it starts from the gray words. Not the start of the div. So here's what it looks like when I code it

[image]

So what I basically want to do is start the margin from the div. Not the text. Here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/R2FVL/. Any help would be great

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - Make divs align horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103/css-make-divs-align-horizontally)

Comment: Your HTML is kind of a mess but you can just do width=50%; I think

Comment: No luck @Pheonixblade9

Comment: And the other post didn't make it work. I tried that before posting this post @Pheonixblade9

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the label and give that a fixed width.

```
<span class="label">Stuff</span>
<span class="stuff">Value Stuff</span>

.label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: yeah. you would  use a fixed width for the left column.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap H2_3 and H2_7 with div

```
 <div id="Div_H2_3"><h2 id="H2_3">More Stuff</h2></div>
 <div id="Div_H2_7"><h2 id="H2_7">Even More Stuff</h2></div>
```

add blow style

```
#Div_H2_7,#Div_H2_3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:35%
}
```

Refer http://jsfiddle.net/F7gG7/