# Rearranging HTML elements with css

Tags: html, css

I have in my layout three elements like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="element1"/>
    <div id="element2"/>
    <div id="element3"/>
</div>
```

shown this way:

```
| element1 | element2 | element3 |
```

I want them to show like this:

```
element1 | element2
element3 |
```

The closest thing I've achieved to do is this:

```
element1 |
element3 | element2
```

I can't achieve to align element1 and element2

Does anybody knows how to do it only with CSS ?

Comment: Add the code that didn't work well to your question. Anyway, `float: left` should do it

Comment: Are you aware your interior div tags are in valid as written? Always close div tags `<div></div>`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working example

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="element1" class="boxes">
    This is elem1
    </div>
    <div id="element2" class="boxes">
    This is the elem2
    </div>
    <div id="element3">
    This is elem3
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .boxes{
        border:1px solid black;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        width:50%;
        float:left;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite open-ended (no context whatsoever), there's a very simple solution, which is to use `float: left`...

```css
#element1, #element2, #element3 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box; // <- Not necessary for this basic example unless you add padding, etc.
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="element1">El 1</div>
    <div id="element2">El 2</div>
    <div id="element3">El 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you use div tags :

```
<div class="exampleclass">Example Text</div>
```

An example made by Sören Kuklau can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37125/5028489)
Here is an example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oopxoatu/) using the `float: left` css property

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it only using CSS because CSS can't do real DOM modifications for that you have to use jQuery.

I hope this link can help you:

[What is the easiest way to order a <UL>/<OL> in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

define them all as `float: left` and add `clear: both` to the third one.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="element1">El 1</div>
    <div id="element2">El 2</div>
    <div id="element3">El 3</div>
</div>





#container > div {
 float: left;
}
#container{
 position:relative;
}
#element3{ 
 bottom: -40px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}
```

In my explaination the `#container` `#element3` and `#container > div` are ids of div so please dont read as comment thanks

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Oh sorry and thanks, But i did not comment as you can see `#container` is an id of div thats why it is showing as comment on my code, and I will remind it next time :)