# Align container with 3 divs horizontally

Tags: html, css, containers

I have tried making a container with 3 divs to make three boxes line up horizontally. The center box doesn't align at the top and bottom with the left box and the third box is far below the first two. I researched a bit about this but the changes I tried to make didn't change this.

Thank you so much!

[Link that shows photo of final page and the issue that I am having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5Kdl.jpg)

Html code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left">
<p>
Tarata Community Engagement
</p>
<a href="http://www.onlythebridge.com/?page_id=28" class="tarata" target="_blank"><img src="tarata.jpg" width="400" height="267" alt="Tarata Community Engagement Project" /></a></div>
<div class="center">
<p>
Santa Rosa Community Engagement
</p>
<img src="santa-rosa.jpg" width="400" height="267" alt="Santa Rosa Community Engagement Project" />
</div>
<div class="right">
<p>
Our histories are unique. The places that we root ourselves, the communities that we are part of, and the ways those relationships change over time are both personal and shared experiences. 
<br><br>
What place/s are meaningful to you? Why? <br>
What are your roots? What do they mean to you in your life?<br>
How do you carry meaningful places and your roots with you? <br>
What is home to you? <br>
Have you left any places or communities behind, what's that like? 
</p></div>
</div>
```

Styling code in xhtml doc:

```
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
text-align:left;

}
.left {
float: left;
margin-left:100px;
max-width: 300px;

}
.center {
float: center;
margin-left: 650px;
max-width: 300px;

}
.right {
float: right;
margin-right: 100px;
max-width: 410px;

}
```

Comment: ?? float:center ? where did you find that could be a possible value for float ?

Answer (score 1):

Does this help? You can use flex to align three columns like you're trying to do. Flex does not work in IE (http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

```css
.container {
  /* Important for columns */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap; /*EDIT: will wrap into 1 column if screen small */
}

.item {
  /* Important for columns */
  flex: 1 1 0;
  border: 3px solid #808080;
  height: 52px;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Remove duplicate borders */

.item-2 {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item item-1">
  Image or text here - 1
  </div>
  
  <div class="item item-2">
  Image or text here - 2 
  </div>
  
  <div class="item item-3">
  Image or text here - 3
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this did help! It's not responsive, but it helped a lot. Thank you so much.

Comment: @caverbook What do you mean by responsive? 1 row of 3, turns to 3 rows of 1 when the screen width is changed? Or something else.

Comment: If you add `flex-wrap:wrap;` to the container, it may behave more like you want. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a float: center unfortunately.

Consult [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103/css-make-divs-align-horizontally) as it might give you a better idea of what to do. Also the above works if you can use flex!